# Sending ADA to multiple wallets in a single transaction

Tags: ada, utxo, output

We are looking options that current exist for sending 20-40ADA to multiple wallets (20+) simultaneously in a single transaction. Initially the need might only be 10 receiving wallets but might scale rather quickly.

What are some current solutions known by the community for performing this action?

I am aware of this tool by CardaHubs; admittedly I haven't actually used it yet. I would like to hear others perspectives on its limitations. https://cardahub.io/tools

Are there any other tools available besides writing a custom script for these transactions each time?  The addresses will be the same or at least similar sometimes but also new ones fairly regularly.

Thank you all in advance for sharing what you know and any insights, ideas or suggestions.

Comment: In Cardano (and I am pretty sure most other cryptos) there are limits to how big a transaction can be (the limit is set in bytes).  As long as the total transaction is within that limit, there is no restriction on how many outputs a single transaction can have. I am pretty sure you can build such a multi-output transaction with `cardano-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Eternl wallet Transaction Builder if you don't want to do it using scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a node (which it sounds like with a name like 'CarPool') then to send ADA and/or native tokens in one trx you can use multiple `--tx-out` options within the `cardano-cli transaction build-raw` command.

Each `--tx-out` will contain the recipient address, assest(s) and amount of each to send.

Depending on the frequency that you will be sending out ADA, you could use some Linux scripting to make this process reasonably dynamic each time you want to send out. For example import data from a pre-built list of addresses, assets and the amount to send, calculate the fee, build the full trx, and submit.